# java, how to count the most frequent day in a gregorion year(Years between 1583 and 4000)?

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar

How can I build an algorithm in Java which when is given a year it will find the most frequent day of the week from that specific year?

Preconditions:

- Week starts on Monday.
- Year is between 1583 and 4000.
- Calendar is Gregorian.

Examples:

```
mostFrequentDays(2427) => {"Friday"}
mostFrequentDays(2185) => {"Saturday"}
mostFrequentDays(2860) => {"Thursday", "Friday"}
```

The given is a integer which is number between 1583 and 4000 and the function returns as a string array the most frequent day/s

```
  public static String[] mostFrequentDays(int year) {
             String[] day= new String[];
             return day;  
  }
public static boolean isGregorianLeapYear(int year) {
              boolean isLeap = false;
              if (year%4==0) isLeap = true;
              if (year%100==0) isLeap = false;
              if (year%400==0) isLeap = true;
              return isLeap;
           }
         public static int dayOfYear(int y, int m, int d) {
              int c = 0;
              for (int i=1; i<m; i++) { // Number of months passed
                 c = c + daysInGregorianMonth(y,i);
              }
              c = c + d;
              return c;      
           }
           public static int daysInGregorianMonth(int y, int m) {
              int d = (int)((m-1)/7);
              if (m==2 && isGregorianLeapYear(y)) d++;
              return d;      
           }
         public static int dayOfWeek(int y, int m, int d) {
              int w = 1; // 01-Jan-0001 is Monday, so base is Sunday
              y = (y-1)%400 + 1; // Gregorian calendar cycle is 400 years
              int ly = (y-1)/4; // Leap years passed
              ly = ly - (y-1)/100; // Adjustment
              ly = ly + (y-1)/400; // Adjustment
              int ry = y - 1 - ly; // Regular years passed
              w = w + ry; // Regular year has one extra week day
              w = w + 2*ly; // Leap year has two extra week days
              w = w + dayOfYear(y,m,d); 
              w = (w-1)%7 + 1;
              return w;
           }
```

I have these functions, but I'm not sure how to use them to count each day in a specific year

Comment: Find what day of the week 1 January of the year is.  Count 1 for each day to the first Monday.  Then count whole weeks adding 1 for each day for each week.  Then count the last remaining days until 31 December for the last part week.  Basically, work through the problem systematically.

Comment: I had almost finished my answer last time you posted the same question. Then you deleted the question and I could not post my answer. Now it’s lost.

Comment: Are you writing and using your own methods as an exercise? If so, it’s a good exercise. For production code one never would nor should. It’s much simpler and much more reliable to use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And yes, it follows the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: oh didn't realise it would do that. real sorry :-(

Answer (score -1):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects, given a year init 2 dates: First id 1.1.'year' second is 31.12.'year'. Check the day of each date using `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

In an array of size 7 keep track of the days from 1.1.'year' to the first Monday (exclusive) and from Monday (inclusive) to 31.12.'year' (inclusive). Find highest indices in that array.

Comment: does this calender follow gregorian time?

Comment: @rokkcrow use subclass https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: I certainly recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *does this calender follow gregorian time?* Not necessarily. It follows the calendar of the supplied locale if it can, or the default locale of the JVM if you don’t specify one.

Comment: At OP's requirements, I believe any date class which can convert date to day of week would work

Comment: I tried `Calendar` with ja-JP locale, year 2020 and the dates you mentioned. I got day of week as 4 and 5, which I take to mean Wednesday and Thursday. I then used th-TH locale instead and got 4 for both dates. No, your suggestion does not always work. In some calendars there are not 31 days in the 12th month. In some calendars the week has a length different from 7 days.